# Webdriver in Python - Executing JavaScript file and passing arguments to its function

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I need to execute function written in JavaScript and also pass arguments.

```
value = driver.execute_script(open("path/file.js").read())
```

I can execute that file but I don't know how to pass arguments to that function.
Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that I can pass arguments like that:

```
value = driver.execute_script(open("path/file.js").read(), "arg1", "arg2")
```

However, I had to change my JavaScript function. 
Now, it looks like that:

```
return (function click_on_element(path, method) {

  ...

})(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
```

I discovered that it is called a self-invoking function. Now, it is possible to pass arguments to JavaScript function and execute it using python and webdriver.